# Why does MacVim have an option for space in listchar while Linux' Vim doesn't?

Tags: linux, macos, vim

Ehy does MacVim have an option for space in listchar while Linux' Vim doesn't?

I am using vim 7.4 in both Linux and OS X.

Comment: Install the same version with the same patch-level to get the same features.

Comment: the space argument to the listchar settings has been added later in the 7.4 release cycle.